# How do I format numbers in excel to use in an IN statement

Tags: sql-server, excel-formula

I'm trying to select a long row of numbers using an IN statement.

How do I format this in excel to be able to drop into my SSMS?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. What does Excel have to do this it here? Are you talking about VBA? You need to elaborate more here. We can't see what you see, and we have nothing to go on apart from a vague requirement.

Comment: Have a formula that concatenates a comma to each cell containing a number. Copy the concatenated result and trim off the trailing comma?

Comment: Or just copy and paste the rows. Then put your cursor at the beginning of the second line. use <shift> + <alt> and scroll down to the bottom. Type a comma and a space.

Comment: Can you supply an example of how your worksheet is structured?

Comment: Notepad++. Copy, paste, mass replace \t with `,` or `','`, check start and back for missing apostrophe, paste into SSMS, and F5. This isn't an answer to your question (hence the comment), but this is far more flexible to learn to do. Notepad++ and I'm sure most other text editors are great for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CONCAT to add commas and string delimiters if needed.
`=CONCAT("'",A1,"',")`
OR
`=CONCAT(A1,",")`

Comment: In my opinion TEXTJOIN would work better in this case: `=TEXTJOIN(",",True,A1:A10)` or `="'" & TEXTJOIN("','",True,A1:A10) & "'"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - that does look highly suitable for the task as it means no odd delimiters to handle and puts the results all in a single cell/string . Looks like it is limited to a result of 32,767 characters though

Comment: @ScottCraner you're probably right. However, I tend to keep one value per line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use excel to add the commas. Paste your list of numbers vertically in your IN statement then set your cursor at the end of the top number, hold 'alt' + 'shift' and arrow all the way down to the second last number then press ',' and it'll insert them all the way down.